# AutoCompleteTextView handling with screen orientation change

Tags: android

I am facing this problem that when the screen orientation is changed from potrait to landscape then the application crashes especially when the drop down is showing. I have written multiple codes for handling this using onRestoreInstanceState() etc. Please tell me if i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Post your code once..

The source code for that particular exception appears to have been updated with a rather more helpful error message:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    mPrivateFlags |= SAVE_STATE_CALLED;
    if (state != BaseSavedState.EMPTY_STATE && state != null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong state class, expecting View State but "
                + "received " + state.getClass().toString() + " instead. This usually happens "
                + "when two views of different type have the same id in the same hierarchy. "
                + "This view's id is " + ViewDebug.resolveId(mContext, getId()) + ". Make sure "
                + "other views do not use the same id.");
    }
}
```

If you use java code for creating layouts this problem may occur..
Ideally you would be using XML for your layout. It'll make your life significantly easier.

Hope this helps..